# bluebird promise.method to wraps a function return a promise,is that ok?

Tags: promise, bluebird

using bluebird in my code , and I use promise.method to cover a original functions just like the api say.Then I write a function which return a promise,and use promise.method to cover it.Those two function return the same:

```
function () {
    var ret = new Promise(INTERNAL);
    ret._captureStackTrace();
    ret._pushContext();
    var value = tryCatch(fn).apply(this, arguments);
    ret._popContext();
    ret._resolveFromSyncValue(value);
    return ret;
}
```

Is it ok to use promise.method to cover the function return a promise??

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the code you're showing is internal bluebird code - the actual code is not being shown (it's `fn` captured by closure there).  Do not call any of these methods yourself (like `_resolveFromSyncValue` etc).

Comment: It's ok, it doesn't change the answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Building async APIs with errors

Yes, the point of `Promise.method` is to make methods throw safe - for example if you have a method that looks like:

```
function foo(jsonStr){
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    return getApi(obj.endpoint);
}
```

It might `throw` an error if passed an invalid object - so if you pass it an invalid string it'll throw (instead of reject). This means you have to guard against both thrown errors and rejected promises in your code and add a `} catch(e){` *and* a `.catch(function(e){` to your code.

This form of programming creates a weak and fragile API that  differentiates synchronous and asynchronous errors and might (and will) create race conditions based on when errors happen. **If a function *might* do something asynchronously it *must always* do it asynchronously**. This is [a core concept](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony) of developing asynchronous APIs - otherwise you end up with race conditions and other issues.

#### What `Promise.method` does

`Promise.method` basically wraps your method with a try/catch and converts thrown errors to rejections and returned values to fulfillments. If your `function foo` was a `Promise.method` it would *always* reject on errors instead of throwing. This fixes the race condition issue since your methods now always fail the same way.

```
var foo = Promise.method(function(jsonStr){
    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr); // if this throws - you get a rejection
    return getApi(obj.endpoint);
});
```

#### When not to use it

There are cases where you can get away with not using `Promise.method` - for example when your method's body is in a promise chain or you're 100% sure it won't throw. In general - I find `Promise.method` quite useful.

It also has the added benefit of letting you return plain values from promise returning methods and have them act consistently.

#### So should I wrap functions that return promises with it?

In general - yes. Exceptions apply and YMMV.