# Wrap async method to return a promise (bluebird)

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to wrap some synchronous functions in bluebird promises, so that I can mix them with other asynchronous methods.

I've followed the answer of [another question to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195391/1909531) and created two methods wrapped in a promise:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var foo1 = Promise.method(function(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    return "ret foo1";
});

var foo2 = Promise.method(function(arg){
    console.log(arg);
    return "ret foo1";
});
```

But when calling these methods

```
foo1.then(foo2);
```

I've got this exception

```
    TypeError: Object function () {
    var ret = new Promise(INTERNAL);
    ret._captureStackTrace();
    ret._pushContext();
    var value = tryCatch(fn).apply(this, arguments);
    var promiseCreated = ret._popContext();
    debug.checkForgottenReturns(
        value, promiseCreated, "Promise.method", ret);
    ret._resolveFromSyncValue(value);
    return ret;
} has no method 'then'
```

Comment: Oh, how embarassing. foo1.then() is really stupid. Maybe I mixed the two ways of defining and using promises. The solution of @Gabs00 calls foo1.then() but it is working very differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foo1.then(foo2)` means 'invoke the method `then` on `foo1`'. But `foo1` does not have a property `then`. However, the *result of a call to `foo1` does*, as the result will be a Promise.

For reference, Bluebird's [`Promise#method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) returns a function:

> Returns a new function that wraps the given function `fn`.

So what you are looking to do instead is this:

```
foo1('string').then(foo2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually call `foo1()` like this:

```
foo1("hello").then(foo2);
```

`foo1` is a function that returns a promise.  You have to call it to get the promise returned.

Working snippet:

```js
var foo1 = Promise.method(function(arg){
    log(arg);
    return "ret foo1";
});

var foo2 = Promise.method(function(arg){
    log(arg);
    return "ret foo1";
});

foo1("hello").then(foo2);

function log(x) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = x;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bluebird/3.0.5/bluebird.js"></script>
```

You may also want to know that `foo2` does not have to return a promise so you don't need `Promise.method()` with it unless you want to be able to call it first in the chain.  Regular functions can be `.then()` handlers.

Comment: This answer gives the solution, too. Both answers were given at the same time. Unfortunately, I can only accept one answer :-(

Answer (score 1):

Note that promises return promises. So foo2 is unnecessary as a promise.

Here is a solution creating a promise instead of using promise.method.

Also, I include an example of using a function that is not a promise, but showing that it returns a promise anyway.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var foo1 = new Promise(function(resolve){
    resolve("ret foo1");
});

var foo2 = new Promise(function(resolve){
    resolve("ret foo2");
});

function foo3(arg){
  console.log('Promises return promises');
  return arg;
}

foo1.then(foo3).then(foo2).then(function(arg){
  console.log(arg);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, that foo2 is unnecessary a promise. But in your example the body of foo1 and foo2 is never called. foo3 is called as wanted. So in your example using a promise is even false. foo1 is only used as a starting point. Am I right?